# Submitting the value in the property tag to the action form

Tags: forms, jsp, properties, struts2, submit

**The JSP:**

```
<s:form action = "addfriend">
  <s:property value="Username" />
  <s:submit value="Add friend" />
</s:form>
```

Does this code submit the value in the `<s:property>` tag to the action form?

Answer (score 3):

No, [`<s:property>` tag](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/property-tag.html) doesn't generate input fields. Merely description of the `<s:property>` tag you can find [here](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/property-tag.html). It's used to print the value from the value stack to JSP output. To submit the value to the action the form needs to have a tag which generate a HTML `<input>` tag or `<textarea>` tag. That's what the [`<s:textfield>`](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/textfield-tag.html) tag provides.

```
<s:textfield name="Username" value="%{Username}"/>
```

Note, there are many other tags that generate input fields, you can see the output generated in HTML browser source window.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to send a value that is displayed through `s:property`, simply add an `s:hidden` field to it:

```
<s:form action = "addfriend">
    <s:hidden    name = "Username"   />
    <s:property value = "Username"   />
    <s:submit   value = "Add friend" />
</s:form>
```

Remember, if a tag doesn't have the `name` attribute, it won't be posted to the Action.

Also avoid variables starting with an uppercase letter: `username` would be mapped to `setUsername` and `getUsername`, but `Username` could create problems, and is not standard.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed by @Roman, here's the code :

You can do :

```
<s:form action="addfriend">
      <s:textfield name="Username"/>
      <s:submit value="Add friend" />
</s:form>
```